# Javascript charting library which can do y-axis --> Time and x-axis ---> Date

Tags: javascript, date, time, charts

I am looking for a Javascript chart library which can produce charts where on the Y-Axis is the Time and on the X-Axis is the Date.

I have an overview here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_charting_frameworks

But if anyone knows something I would like to hear it :-)

Greetings and thanks in advance!

Marco

Answer (score 4):

[ZingChart](http://www.zingchart.com) can easily handle this. The scale objects accept Unix time values (in milliseconds) as values, and the "transform" object can be used to transform the Unix time into a more human-readable format using the tokens seen in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/up6e6zfu/1/) and on [this doc page](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/json-attributes-syntax/scale-objects/transform/). [This Epoch Converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) is a useful tool for converting to Unix time.

Here's the sample scale-x configuration from the jsfiddle demo:

```
"scaleX": {
        "min-value": 1373045400000,
        "step": "day",
        "transform": {
            "type": "date",
            "all": "%d %M %Y",
            "item": {
                "visible": false
            },
            "guide": {
                "visible": true
            }
        }
    },
```

I'm on the ZingChart team, so let me know if you need any more help.